# QtLocation and OpenStreetMap: is it possible to get English labels in non-English countries?

Tags: qt, qml, openstreetmap, qtlocation

I'm using a `Map` QML class from `QtLocation` (plugin `osm`) on my QML widget.

I want to scroll the viewport to some arabian countries, but the labels there are with Arabian letters, not Latin! I don't understand none of them.

Cannot I somehow switch the labels to English?

Comment: Labels are part of the tiles ie. a label text is drawn on a tile, they are inseparable one from another. I would advice you to use another server if that's possible, I just don't know how this plugin works. More info could be found [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_internationalization). But anyway, a title could be shown in English if is only has `name:en` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying language is not supported by the *osm* plugin of QtLocation.
Other plugins on the other hand seem to support that feature, like the *esri* plugin or the *here* plugin, by setting the locale